# How to insert a number of dynamic fields into a mongoDB array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the following code in my page. Whenver I click on the "Add new field button" a new fields gets added to the page. What I need to accomplish is to insert every single new field into my mongodb database array.

```
    function addInput(divName){
        if (counter == limit)  {
            alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
        }
        else {
            var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
            newdiv.className = "row-inputs";
            newdiv.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="productName" placeholder="product name" class="q-product-name">'  + 
            '<input type="number" name="quantity" placeholder="1" class="q-quantity" value=1>' +
            '<input type="text" name="pricePerUnit" placeholder="price" class="q-price">' +
            '<input type="text" name="itemTotal" placeholder="price" class="q-total">';
            document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

The above is my schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var InventorySchema = Schema({
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now },
    name: String,
    list: [{
        product_name: String,
        quantity: Number,
        pricePerUnit: Number,
        itemTotal: Number
    }],
    invoiceTotal: Number,
    comment: String,
    dueDate: Date
})

var inventory = mongoose.model('inventory', InventorySchema);

module.exports = inventory;
```

How can I tell mongoose to add every fields created dynamically to my database?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can not insert new fields if you have defined a static schema with types defined.

However, You can specify type of an attribute ({}) it will allow anything to be saved to it. If you want one of your object or whole schema dynamic then you can define a schema like this:

```
var InventorySchema = Schema({
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now },
    name: String,
    list: [{ }],
    invoiceTotal: Number,
    comment: String,
    dueDate: Date
})
```

> Caution: You will not be able to validate or typecast any of your
>   dynamic variables.

Comment: In that case, how would I loop true each different product? So far, I only get one "product name" with different values, instead a several product name with its own value.

Comment: unable to understand your concern. can you post the code snippet?